# How to add data to TableView on iphone?

Tags: iphone, arrays, uitableview

I defined an array for tableView's listData.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sleep", @"Bashful", @"Happy", nil];
self.listData = array;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
cell.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
```

Now I want to add more data to the tableview. How to connect another data to it so when I click a button the array will be @"A", "B", "C", "D", nil?

Comment: This looks an awful lot like some of the code in "Beginning iPhone Development", about a chapter behind the one I'm reading now.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also reading that book right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the NSMutableArray with insertObjetcAtIndex or addObject:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sleep", @"Bashful", @"Happy", nil];
[array insertObject:@"XYZ" atIndex:3];
[array addObject:@"ABC"];
```

Comment: I want to add some new objects later(after viewDidLoad method). How to call the UITableView's data source method again to reload the new data?

Comment: You can call the method reloadData from your UITableView:
[table reloadData];